# How to fetch data from mongodb into html table usnig node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working in a project and I am at a state where I need to fetch data from mongodb and show all the data in tabular format in a html table but the problem is I don't know how to do that so please help me.

Well I know how to fetch data from mongodb in node js using mongoose, I also know how to display that in HTML or hbs but I don't know how to display that in an html table, I don't know how to put every data in their respective cell in html table, So please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the map of the forEach function to show the data in the HTML table.
The Point is, you have to render the s with the data like this

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% data.forEach((item) => { %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= item._id %></td>
        <td><%= item.name %></td>
        <td><%= item.email %></td>
      </tr>
    <% }); %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Assuming you have an array of objects coming from Node js when fetching it.
SO for every object, it will add a new row to your table.

Note:- The syntax depends on which framework you are using.

Let me know if you are clear or not.

Comment: This is using ejs templates. OP states "I also know how to display that in HTML or hbs " so would be better to give a handlebars example.